# How can I plot x with mutiple y values？

Tags: r, ggplot2, stat

I would like to plot these.

```
   subj type stc key    value
1    2    1   1  X1 94.30562
2    2    1   7  X1 94.30104
3    2    2   1  X1 95.26288
4    2    2   7  X1 94.66240
5    3    1   1  X1 89.52976
6    3    1   7  X1 88.52011
```

- Here, five persons (subj) are required to say sentence1 and sentence7 in two types of intonations.
- On each sentence, there are 60 key points(X1-X60) where the frequency value is extracted.

I would like to make:

- X axis: X1-X60; Y-axis: value;
- different colours to represent two types;
- the line in the plot a smooth line

I tried in this way, but it looks messy:

```
ggplot(data = df0, aes(x = key, y = value))+ 
  geom_line(group = type, color = type)
```

---

Comment: Instead of `geom_line()` use `geom_smooth()`

Comment: From the sample data you've provided it's not clear what you want as your x-axis and as your y-axis? Can you clarify? Is the y-axis `value`?

Comment: What code have you tried? Providing this is better than a picture

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. It’s easier to help if you make your question reproducible: include a minimal dataset in the form of an object for example if a data frame as df <- data.frame(…) where … is your variables and values or use dput(head(df)). Include the code you have tried, as @KJM suggests. These links should be of help: [mre] and [ask]

Comment: I want x-axis to be X1-60 and y-axis to be the value corresponding to X1-60.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `geom_smooth()`, but because your xaxis is a character, you need to use `group=` to force the smooth line:

```
set.seed(111)
df0 = expand.grid(subj=1:3,key=paste0("X",1:60),type=1:2)
df0$value = rnorm(nrow(df0),rep(1:2,each=120))
df0$type = factor(df0$type)

ggplot(df0,aes(x=key,y=value,fill=type,group=type)) + 
geom_smooth() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=4))
```

[image]

Or you can consider changing the keys to numeric:

```
df0$key_num =as.numeric(gsub("X","",as.character(df0$key)))

ggplot(df0,aes(x=key_num,y=value,fill=type)) + 
geom_smooth()
```

[image]